# Узнать $mail после перехода по ссылке

Tags: mail.ru

Собственно вопросик, приходит письмо на почту mail.ru, можно ли после перехода по ссылке внутри письма генерировать ссылку вида xxx.ru/site/?loginmail

т.е узнать логин почты ?
по кукам как-то делается или по другим каким то значениям ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Укажите, какой язык программировагния вы используете (мой внутренний голос подсказывает, что PHP, но будет лучше, если вы это явно укажете в метках вопроса), кто и кому посылает письмо, что происходит (или должно происходить) при переходе по ссылке и т. д..

Comment: При чём тут mail.ru? Другие почтовые сервера не планируется поддреживать?

Comment: Тот кто генерирует тело письма и вставляет туда тег `<a href="">` должен в URL кодировать все необходимые ему данные о пользователе.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант присылать готовую ссылку: xxx.ru/site?login@mail.ru

Но придется для каждого E-Mail отдельно формировать текст.